# Find the exact value of the trigonometric expression when $\sin(u) = − 5 /13$ and $\cos(v) = − 4/ 5$.

Tags: trigonometry

Find the exact value of the trigonometric expression when   $\sin(u) = − 5 /13$ and $\cos(v) = − 4/ 5$.  (Both $u$ and $v$ are anglese in III° quadrant.)

$$\cos(u + v) $$

Comment: $\cos(u+v)=\cos u \cos v - \sin u \sin v$

Answer (score 2):

The sum formula for cosine is: $$\cos(u+v)=\cos(u)\cos(v)−\sin(u)\sin(v)$$.

In order to solve, you can visualize the triangles which define the sine and cosine.

[image: Image of the stated sine and cosine functions]

After this, the problem is rather simple as you only need to plug in the values of cosine and sine that you get.

$$\cos(u+v) = \left(\frac{-12}{13} \cdot \frac{-4}{5}\right) - \left(\frac{-5}{13} \cdot \frac{-3}{5}\right)
= \frac{48}{65} - \frac{15}{65} = \frac{33}{65}$$

Thus, $\cos(u+v) = \frac{33}{65}$.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.